# Shell scripting to How to display the specific contents of the search string?

Tags: unix

Here is my query :

/path/newdir/newfile.csv

Example Input search string:
123456789

Example Output:

Sample Number:   123456789
Time In: 2012-05-29T10:21:06Z
Time Out: 2012-05-29T13:07:46Z

Comment: Welcome to SO Jackie! I'm not sure what your asking for help on here. Can you be more specific? What have you tried?

Comment: HI AI G : I want to find a string in the file newfile.csv located in the path "/path/newdir/newfile.csv"
Nw i've to input a search string as for example : "Input search string: 123456789"
I've to get the output parameters associated with the search string, for example 
Sample output:
Sample Number: 123456789 
Time In: 2012-05-29T10:21:06Z 
Time Out: 2012-05-29T13:07:46Z

i need a shell scripting for the above. Can u plzz help me in this regard /

Comment: Have you tried something? How about grep or awk?

Comment: yup, i tried grep. it finds the string. bt i need to display the specific parameters of that search string.

Comment: What does the newfile.csv look like that grep/awk doesn't work?

Comment: Assume the contents of the newfile.csv looks like this :
Sample Number: 123456789 
Time In: 2012-05-29T10:21:06Z 
Time Out: 2012-05-29T13:07:46Z
some data : gfjgkgkgjg

I need to display Sample Number,Time In: and Time Out:

By using grip command, i can display only 1 parameter

Comment: please edit your question to include these details. Don't make people have to read through a long chain of comments to understand your problem. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with sed,

```
sed '/123456789/s/\(Sample Number.*\) \(Time In.*\) \(Time Out: [^ ]\+\) \(.*\)/\1 \2 \3/g' newfile.csv
```

I think your newfile.csv looks like this only.I think so.

File Content:

```
Sample Number: 123456789 Time In: 2012-05-29T10:21:06Z Time Out: 2012-05-29T13:07:46Z some data : gfjgkgkgjg
```

I hope this will helps you.

Comment: Never pipe grep to sed.  Use sed to select: `sed '/pattern/s/...//'` is exactly the same as `grep pattern | sed 's/...//'`

Comment: @ Sat : Thank U very much. It works absolutely fine. I'm very new to this forum.

Comment: @ SAT :
newtext.csv looks like below :
Record 1
----------
Sample Number: 123456789
Time In: 2012-05-29T10:21:06Z
Time Out: 2012-05-29T13:07:46Z
some data : gfjgkgkgjg
some code : 23-87-98-70
Assume there are such 100 records in a newtext.csv
So, now i need the parameters of the entered i/p string, which is something below


Example Input Search String :
123456789

Example Output :
Sample Number: 123456789
Time In: 2012-05-29T10:21:06Z
Time Out: 2012-05-29T13:07:46Z
-------------------------------------
This is what exactly i need. Can you please help me ?

Answer (score 0):

The command grep is used to search for a string in a file. In your example you would do:

```
grep 123456789 /path/newdir/newfile.csv
```

You can also include context in your output with:

```
grep -A <lines before> -B <lines after> 123456789 /path/newdir/newfile.csv
```

Comment: Assume the contents of the newfile.csv looks like this : Sample Number: 123456789 Time In: 2012-05-29T10:21:06Z Time Out: 2012-05-29T13:07:46Z some data : gfjgkgkgjg I need to display Sample Number,Time In: and Time Out: By using grep command, i can display only 1 parameter.
i need to display 3 parameters associated with it.

Answer (score 0):

Let me guess again.

```
Sample Number: 123456789
Time In: 2012-05-29T10:21:06Z
Time Out: 2012-05-29T13:07:46Z
some data : gfjgkgkgjg
```

We can use awk:

```
awk -v re=gfjgkgkgjg -F ": " '$1~/^Sample Number$/{sn=$2}$1~/^Time In$/{tin=$2}$1~/^Time Out$/{out=$2}$1~/^some data $/{data=$2}$2~re{print"Sample Number: "sn" Time In: "tin" Time Out: "out" Data: "data}'
```

If you are matching against last line you will need to add some state automation to print collected data at last record line.